# Can't update table 'attendance_tbl' in stored function/trigger error for trigger delete

Tags: mysql, triggers

trigger:

```
    DELIMITER $$

    USE `smartclass_dbv2`$$

   CREATE TRIGGER `delete_attendance_on_holiday`
   AFTER INSERT ON `attendance_tbl`
   FOR
     EACH ROW 
     BEGIN
       DELETE T1
       FROM
          `attendance_tbl` T1
       LEFT JOIN
           announcement_tbl T2
       ON
           old.T1.date = T2.announcement_date
       WHERE
              old.T1.date = T2.announcement_date
           and
              announcement_tbl.announcement_description = 'holiday'; 
     END$$
```

> the scenario is any attendance on the day that is holiday will be deleted. In the announcement_tbl, it contains announcement_date, announcement_description, announcement_date. if the date of the announcement is same with the date on the attendance table provided that the description is holiday, it will void/delete the  attendance rows on the attendance table. HOWEVER, when im inserting data on the ATTENDANCE_tbl, error happens.
>   Can u help me figure out the problem?

This is the error:

"Can't update table 'attendance_tbl' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.""

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error: Can't update table 'tbl' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481100/mysql-error-cant-update-table-tbl-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to delete *all* the rows in attendance, only the one being inserted.  For this, you error out on the insertion:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `smartclass_dbv2`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `delete_attendance_on_holiday` BEFORE INSERT ON `attendance_tbl`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM announcement_tbl a
               WHERE a.announcement_description = 'holiday' AND
                     a.announcement_date = new.date
              ) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000', message_text = 'Insert failed; date on holiday';
    END IF;
END$$
```

You may want a similar trigger for `update`s.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''45000', message_text = 'Insert failed; date on holiday';
    END IF;
END' at line 9

Comment: nevermind, haha this solved my problem :) i just rephrased the signal part with: "SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        set message_text = "Insert failed date on holiday";"

THANKS